# Receiving incorrect response from posting JSON to an URL

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to post JSON to an URL but the response seems to be wrong.

```
url = "www.example123.com/someurl"
mypayload = { //JSON PAYLOAD }
response = request.post(url, post = payload, auth = ("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"))
print(response.content)
```

But it does not seem to work. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the expected output? What are you getting? Is there any error?

Comment: I'm getting inappropriate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the appropriate header for the specifying its JSON data.

Try :

```
headers_JSON = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = request.post(url, JSON = mypayload, headers = headers_JSON, auth = ("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"))
```

Also note, instead of `post = payload`, use `JSON = payload`.

If that doesn't work use:

`post = JSON.dumps(payload)`

A quick look at the documentation will help : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: Awesome man. It worked. I'm getting the relevant response now with the use of headers and JSON = mypayload .

Answer (score 1):

```
var retval = jQuery.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url: url,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

You can see in above jquery ajax we are setting **content Type** to "application/json"

You can see in your request payload what it is. It all depends upon what your server API is expecting means Content Type.